# aws cli under docker - Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb:///path

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I already know there are questions that appears to be the same, hovewer none of the answers satisfied me.

I created a project from quarkus lambda example [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda)

Then I launched manage.sh create, which contains the following statement:

```
LAMBDA_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::[etc]

aws lambda create-function \
--function-name ${FUNCTION_NAME} \
--handler ${HANDLER} \
--runtime ${RUNTIME} \
--role ${LAMBDA_ROLE_ARN} \
--timeout 15 \
--memory-size 256 \
--zip-file ${ZIP_FILE} \
${LAMBDA_META}

FUNCTION_NAME=QuarkusAmazonLambdaArchetype
HANDLER=io.quarkus.amazon.lambda.runtime.QuarkusStreamHandler::handleRequest
RUNTIME=java11
ZIP_FILE=fileb:///Users/myuser/java_workspace/quarkus/quarkus-amazon-lambda-archetype/target/function.zip
```

When I launch the script, the following output appears:

```
Error parsing parameter '--zip-file': Unable to load paramfile fileb:///Users/myuser/java_workspace/quarkus/quarkus-amazon-lambda-archetype/target/function.zip: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/myuser/java_workspace/quarkus/quarkus-amazon-lambda-archetype/target/function.zip'
```

I'm really frustrated because file exists (tried with ls ) and file has all read privileges.

I've also tried changing absolute path with relative, but with no luck.

I'm using aws cli with docker on MacOS big sur

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

As I'm using cli with docker, following the [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-docker.html) I realised all host content is moved under directory */aws* in container.

Thus changing --zip-file to:

```
fileb:///aws/target/function.zip
```

worked for me

Answer (score -1):

`Users/myuser` is a windows path, not linux. As shown in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html), for windows you need to prefix path with drive letter, e.g.:

```
fileb://C:\Users\myuser\java_workspace\quarkus\quarkus-amazon-lambda-archetype\target\function.zip
```

Comment: I'm using macos, however after thinking a bit more  I guess why it doesn't work. I have first to add file in container and then run the script